# Rewrite anything except existing files

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I basically want to rewrite any request starting with `foo/` to `foo/index.php?url=`. For example, `http://localhost/foo/something` should become `http://localhost/foo/index.php?url=something`.

I currently have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(\w*) foo/index.php?url=$1
```

This works on my localhost, but not on a free hosting service online. The point is, that it there also rewrites existing files... So my layout has gone, as well as all images etc, because `foo/style.css` becomes `foo/index.php?url=style.css`. This isn't happening on my localhost.

I came across this similar question: [mod_rewrite: Redirect if anything but a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399090/mod-rewrite-redirect-if-anything-but-a-file), but it didn't do anything actually.

So how would I go about rewriting anything except existing files here? Why does it only work on my own localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^foo/(\w*) foo/index.php?url=$1
```

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(\w*)$ foo/index.php?url=$1
```

with added `$` sign. But this doesn't rewrite URLs with non-word chars like a dot (so `foo/style.css` wont be rewritten).

Comment: My host now says my disk usage is full whilst it clearly isn't... I guess I'll just move to another host, this just sucks. Your suggestion still works on my localhost, so I'll use that if I happen to find a working free host. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you add the extension to the regex? That is to say requestion the `dot` not to be present?

```
RewriteRule ^foo/[^.]+ foo/index.php?url=$1
```

Or I guess you can add the $ to your own

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(\w*)$ foo/index.php?url=$1
```

Cause else it can match files since foo/style matches (you did not require next char to be end of URL)

How is it?